# Bootstrap JS not working with Middleman

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, middleman

Attempting to get a very simple bootstrap site up and running the JS/jQuery for the dropdowns appears to not be working.

gemfile

```
#default stuff...
gem "sass"
gem "bootstrap-sass","~> 3.3.5", :require => false
```

layout

```
<!-- ... -->
<%= javascript_include_tag "all" %>
<!-- ... -->
```

all.js

```
//=require_tree .
```

Then the html is copy and pasted from the default bootstrap Nav Bar: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

The CSS works and the nav bar properly collapses to a hamburger icon, but clicking any anchor tag results in zero changes to the page. I've tried requiring jQuery and bootstrap stuff in different ways in all.js, the Gemfile, and the layout.erb, without any success. What super simple thing am I missing here?

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First time I've used Yahoo search and found better results than Google. I found [a blogger who had the answer](http://jotdashed.com/stupidly%20simple%20tips/2015/02/12/middleman-bootstrap-and-jquery.html) thank goodness!

Gemfile

```
gem "bootstrap-sass", "~> 3.3.5", :require => false 
gem "jquery-middleman" #Don't forget to run 'bundle install'
```

all.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

all.js

```
//= require jquery  
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require tree .
```

The 'require tree .' works but has caused problems for me in a previous Rails project. Sometimes jQuery can be included twice, so when you click a dropdown it opens and closes faster than you can see and you think it's not working at all. It seems like it is working, but just be wary of that.

Happy coding!